# Handling DataAccessException in Spring Security

Tags: database, exception, spring-security

Right now I've got Spring Security protecting an application using basic authentication. The user details are coming from a JDBC source. If the database goes down, the internals of the user loading mechanism will throw a `DataAccessException`. The default authentication provider class, `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, catches the exception and maps it back to an `AuthenticationServiceException`. The end result of such a mapping is that the browser/client receives HTTP code 401.

What I want to do is to handle database unavailability in a different way. At the very least, I want this to be handled by responding with HTTP 503 but I would prefer if it redirected to an error page. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** Ritesh's solution was partially correct. The missing steps apart from implementing your own Basic entry point is to also use v3.0.3 of the security schema so that the `<http-basic/>` element has the `entry-point-ref` attribute. If you don't use this special attribute, the default Basic filter will always use its own Basic entry point implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` sends 401 for `AuthenticationException`. You can create your own custom entry point to handle `AuthenticationServiceException` and send out 503.

Other option is not to do anything in entry point and use `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` and/or implement your own `HandlerExceptionResolver`.